# Data Structures - lists

Tags: python, data-structures

This is homework but the lesson gives me the answer already. I'm having trouble putting the words from the answer to the line of code

```
 #Calculate all the primes below 1000

  result = [1]
  candidates = range(3, 1000)
  base = 2
  product = base

  while candidates:
      while product < 1000:
          if product in candidates:
              candidates.remove(product)
          product = product + base
      result.append(base)
      base = candidates[0]
      product = base
      del candidates[0]

  result.append(base)
  print result
```

This is a version of "The Sieve of Erastothenes."

This is the explanation that was given to me.

New things in this example…

The built-in function range actually returns a list that can be used like all other lists. (It includes the first index, but not the last.) A list can be used as a logic variable. If it is not empty, then it is true — if it is empty, then it is false. Thus, while candidates means “while the list named candidates is not empty” or simply “while there are still candidates”. You can write if someElement in someList to check if an element is in a list. You can write someList.remove(someElement) to remove someElement from someList. You can append an element to a list by using someList.append(something). Actually, you can use + too (as in someList = someList+[something]) but it is not as efficient. You can get at an element of a list by giving its position as a number (where the first element, strangely, is element 0) in brackets after the name of the list. Thus someList[3] is the fourth element of the list someList. (More on this below.) You can delete variables by using the keyword del. It can also be used (as here) to delete elements from a list. Thus del someList[0] deletes the first element of someList. If the list was [1,2,3] before the deletion, it would be [2,3] afterwards.

Before going on to explaining the mysteries of indexing list elements, I will give a brief explanation of the example.

This is a version of the ancient algorithm called “The Sieve of Erastothenes” (or something close to that). It considers a set (or in this case, a list) of candidate numbers, and then systematically removes the numbers known not to be primes. How do we know? Because they are products of two other numbers.

We start with a list of candidates containing numbers [2..999] — we know that 1 is a prime (actually, it may or may not be, depending on who you ask), and we wanted all primes below 1000. (Actually, our list of candidates is [3..999], but 2 is also a candidate, since it is our first base). We also have a list called result which at all times contains the updated results so far. To begin with, this list contains only the number 1. We also have a variable called base. For each iteration (“round”) of the algorithm, we remove all numbers that are some multible of this base number (which is always the smallest of the candidates). After each iteration, we know that the smallest number left is a prime (since all the numbers that were products of the smaller ones are removed — get it?). Therefore, we add it to the result, set the new base to this number, and remove it from the candidate list (so we won’t process it again.) When the candidate list is empty, the result list will contain all the primes. Clever, huh?

What I don't understand is where they say, 'we remove all numbers that are some multiple of this base number.' Where is that in the line of code? Can someone explain line by line what the program is doing? I am a newb at this trying to understand the mechanics on each line of code and why. Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the start of each of the `while candidates:` loops, `product` equals `base`. Then in that loop you have another loop, `while products < 1000`. At the end of this loop you increment `product` by `base`. So `product` goes through each multiple of `base`. You then remove all the values of `product` which is where you "remove multiples of the base number".

Basically what the program is doing is:

```
...
set product to base

for each candidate
    for each multiple of base, referred to as 'product'
        remove product from candidates
    set base to new value
    reset product to new base
    ...
```

Comment: so 'set base to new value,' what is the new value and where does it get that value from?

Comment: @G.G `base` will be set to the "smallest number left" (as you said in the question) which you know to be prime.

Comment: one more thing... so when we start the loop for    while product < 1000: if product in candidates: - 2 isn't inside the list for candidates so what happens to the 2?

Comment: @G.G You can see that after the `while product < 1000` loop, we append `base` to the `result` list. So `2` will be added to the list of primes.

Comment: Ok. I get everything up to that point.
    base = candidates[0] - What is that doing?
    product = base - Does this apply before the next line below?
    del candidates[0] - ?

If we were using 2, how is 2 = candidates[0]? 
After all that is said and done, the last two lines: result.append(base) and print result are throwing me off for the output since result.append(base) is mentioned already within the first loop.

Comment: @G.G As I said before, that line sets base to the "smallest number left" or the "smallest number in `candidates` left" or `candidates[0]`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3600/discussion-between-g-g-and-quasiverse)